# TFS 2017 WebLayout - Add field to Attachment tab

Tags: tfs

We are starting to look at the new WebLayout feature of TFS 2017.

I understand the system controls and that Microsoft has limited this on purpose.

What we currently have for the work items is a textbox above the **AttachmentControl** that shows some instructions on how to use the attachment Control, or better how not to use it. As well as a network path to the server to use in case of very large attachments.

I can't seem to find a away to add items to the new **Attachment** tab. The control is currently page wide on the new tab and no way to add additional controls to that tab.

Is there a workaround that would allow me to add a control to this tab ?

Answer (score 0):

No. You cannot modify system controls. You could [write an extension](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/devops/2017/11/13/creating-work-item-form-extensions-in-visual-studio-team-services/) that pops up your warning text, but you'd have to add it to one of the available "contribution" points.

Comment: Thanks Daniel, just to clarify i do not wish to change a control.
For me it would be enough to be able to add the TextBox control to the attachment tab, but i think the tab as a whole cannot be managed ?